# Tem como simplificar as instruções IF no PHP

Tags: php

Pessoal estou criando um sistema de sorteio em linguagem PHP
aqui um trecho do código que comecei a programar
mas o problema é que existem 19 combinações de acertos diferentes
essa aqui embaixo é apenas a primeira!
existe um meio mais prático de fazer sem precisar usar tantas linhas de instruções IF?

```
<?php
    ...................
    //primeira combinação de acertos
    if (($d1=3) && ($d7=3) && ($d8=3) && ($d9=3) && ($d5=3))
    echo "ganhou 12 pontos";
    if (($d1=2) && ($d7=2) && ($d8=2) && ($d9=2) && ($d5=2))
    echo "ganhou 12 pontos";
    if (($d1=1) && ($d7=1) && ($d8=1) && ($d9=1) && ($d5=1))
    echo "ganhou 12 pontos";
?>
```

complementando, são 19 combinações das variáveis $d1 até $d15, mas pelo visto o amigo resolveu a questão, então basta por 
if( $d1==$d7 && $d7==$d8 && $d8==$d9 && $d9==$d5 )
  echo "ganhou 12 pontos";
pra cada uma das 19 combinações

Comment: Seria bom por a lógica toda na pergunta, pois pode ter um monte de maneiras diferentes de se resolver o problema. Se fossem só estas variáveis, bastaria `if( $d1==$d7 && $d7==$d8 && $d8==$d9 && $d9==$d5 )`  para ver se os números são iguais; Imagino que não sejam só estas 5. Clique em [Edit] e ponha as regras do jogo na pergunta, para ter a chance de obter uma resposta.

Comment: Só não esquecer que **"="** é atribuição. Comparação é **"=="**.

Comment: Lembre-se que `=` é atribuição e `==` é comparação. Cuidado!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda
Bacco, Marcos Regis e Mastria

Comment: é possível reduzir usando técnicas com equações matemáticas.. mas isso depende de como está modelado os dados.

Comment: Pode iniciar com `$d1 == 1` ou `$d1 == 2` dependendo da lógica de pontos pra que fique `if($d1==1 && $d1==$d7 && $d7==$d8 && $d8==$d9 && $d9==$d5 )`, pois a forma como editou independente do número sempre dará 12 pontos se forem iguais.

Comment: A logica é que todos os números tem que ser iguais?

Comment: sim a lógica é que todos os números tem que ser iguais, os números serão 1, 2 e 3, e as variavés $d1 até $d15,  são 19 combinações onde o sorteador ganhará 12 pontos,  essa ( $d1==$d7 && $d7==$d8 && $d8==$d9 && $d9==$d5 )  é uma delas

Answer (score 5):

Outra forma de fazer essas comparações é transformar as variáveis em um array e criar outro array como um gabarito, assim comparasse se os dados enviados pelo usuário são iguais as informações de algum gabarito.

```
<?php

$d1 = 2;
$d7 = 2;
$d8 = 2;
$d9 = 2;
$d5 = 2;

$gabarito['1'] = array_fill(0, 5, 3);
$gabarito['2'] = array_fill(0, 5, 2);
$gabarito['3'] = array_fill(0, 5, 1);

$respondido = array($d1, $d7, $d8, $d9, $d5);

if($respondido === $gabarito[1]){
    echo 'Ganhou 8 pontos';
}else if($respondido === $gabarito[2]){
    echo 'Ganhou 12 pontos/gabarito 2';
}else if($respondido === $gabarito[3]){
    echo 'Ganhou 12 pontos/gabarito 3';
}else{
    echo 'Mais sorte na próxima';
}
```

Pode incrementar um pouco mais e definir um array com os gabaritos e as mensagens/recompensas e fazer uma comparação dentro do foreach, uma vez encontrado um resultado positivo o `break` sai do laço e exibe a mensagem.

```
$gabaritos = array(array('msg' => 'Ganhou 8 pontos', 'respostas' => array_fill(0, 5, 3)),
                   array('msg' => 'Ganhou 12 pontos/ gabarito2', 'respostas' => array_fill(0, 5, 2)),
                   array('msg' => 'Ganhou 12 pontos/ gabarito3', 'respostas' => array_fill(0, 5, 3))                        
            );  


$respondido = array($d1, $d7, $d8, $d9, $d5);


foreach($gabaritos as $gabarito){
    if($respondido === $gabarito['respostas']){
        $msg = $gabarito['msg'];
        break;
    }else{
        $msg = 'Perdeu playboy';
    }
}

echo $msg;
```

**Referência:**

[Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5678959/1342547)

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de reduzir sua comparação é:

```
if($d1.$d7.$d8.$d9.$d5 == 11111) echo 'ganhou 12 pontos';
```

Ou mais preciso:

```
if($d1.$d7.$d8.$d9.$d5 === '11111') echo 'ganhou 12 pontos';
```

É bastante importante explicar sua lógica de pontuação, assim podemos ajudar com diversos métodos de comparação.

Abraço

Comment: já ajudaram muito mas vou tentar dar mais detalhes  são 19 combinações entre $d1 até $d15, essa aí ( $d1==$d7 && $d7==$d8 && $d8==$d9 && $d9==$d5 ) é uma delas, então só por uma if pra cada uma dessas combinações, é isso que vou fazer  fico agradecido à todos pela ajuda

Comment: é um caça-níqueis em HTML5 onde o PHP irá passar as variáveis através dos métodos POST e GET

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a solução mais legível e performática para o problema seria converter as variáveis em uma matriz, e verificar se em cada combinação possui apenas um valor.

```php
$combinacoes = array(
    array($d1,$d5,$d7,$d8,$d9),
    array($d2,$d3,$d4,$d8,$d9),
    array($d3,$d4,$d5,$d6,$d7),
    array($d5,$d6,$d7,$d8,$d9),
    array($d4,$d5,$d6,$d7,$d8)
);

foreach ($combinacoes as $combinacao) {
    if(count(array_unique($combinacao)) === 1) {
        echo 'ganhou 12 pontos';
    }
}
```

É possível ter um ganho de performance ainda maior trocando a funcão `array_unique` por `array_flip`, ficando assim:

```php
$combinacoes = array(
    array($d1,$d5,$d7,$d8,$d9),
    array($d2,$d3,$d4,$d8,$d9),
    array($d3,$d4,$d5,$d6,$d7),
    array($d5,$d6,$d7,$d8,$d9),
    array($d4,$d5,$d6,$d7,$d8)
);

foreach ($combinacoes as $combinacao) {
    if(count(array_flip($combinacao)) === 1) {
        echo 'ganhou 12 pontos';
    }
}
```

Desta forma caso necessite alterar ou adicionar combinações no futuro, será muito mais fácil.

**Referências**

- [Performance das funções array_unique, array_keys e array_flip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321620/array-unique-vs-array-flip)

Answer (score -1):

Toda comparação requer um IF | ELSEIF | SWITCH | $ ? : (operador ternário). Você pode resumir suas comparações em variáveis, para que o IF não fique muito extenso, exemplo:

```
$8pontos = ($d1 == 3 && $d7 == 3 && $d8 == 3 && $d9 == 3 && $d5 ==3) ? true : false;
$12pontos = ($d1 == 1 && $d7 == 1 && $d8 == 1 && $d9 == 5 && $d5 == 7) ? true : false;

$pontos = 0;

if ($8pontos) {
    $pontos = 8;
} elseif ($12pontos) {
    $pontos = 12;
}
```

Inclusive esta é uma prática aconselhável para comparações extensas.

Comment: o correto seria if( $d1==$d7 && $d7==$d8 && $d8==$d9 && $d9==$d5 )  conforme  o Bacco sugeriu, pois essa é apenas uma das 19 condições, onde se ganha os 12 pontos

Comment: isso foi apenas um exemplo para mostrar como se resume uma condição IF, você vai ter que fazer a condição. Esta é uma prática altamente recomendada, procure pelo google. Ainda ganho -1, triste.